# Wrong result in MySQL user defined Function

Tags: mysql

I have the following Mysql user-defined function :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `vacationdays`(schoolyear varchar(9),schoolno int(11)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE vacationdays int(11);
SET vacationdays = (SELECT sum(Days) FROM greenland.vacations
where SchoolNo = schoolno 
And SY = schoolyear
And Date_Format(Now(), "%Y-%m-%d") >= StartDate);
return vacationdays;
END
```

when I call it,SELECT vacationdays("2021/2022",1). it returns 60.

but when I run the same query

```
SELECT sum(Days) FROM greenland.vacations
where SchoolNo = 1 
And SY = "2021/2022"
And
    Date_Format(Now(), "%Y-%m-%d") >= StartDat
```

it returns 30 (the correct result !!!

Noting I have 2 schools in my table with the same vacations days. Looks like the query in the user-defined function ignores the SchoolNo condition !!!

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Change the name of the input parameter from `schoolno` to `_schoolno` (for example) and `... where SchoolNo = _schoolno ...`. See [25.8 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routine-name-conflicts).

Comment: In ```.. where SchoolNo = schoolno ..``` both `schoolno` are local variables defined as function parameter. You must type ```.. where greenland.vacations.SchoolNo = schoolno ..```.

Comment: It works, thank you Akina & Wchiquito for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

I followed [Akina's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71362099/wrong-result-in-mysql-user-defined-function/71369085#comment126137772_71362099) to qualify the attribute in the `WHERE` clause:
`WHERE greenland.vacations.SchoolNo = schoolno`, and it works.